# Simple SPARQL query does not return any results

Tags: sparql, rdf, blazegraph

I am just getting up and running with Blazegraph in embedded mode. I load a few sample triples and am able to retrieve them with a "select all" query:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
```

This query returns all my sample triples:

```
[s=<<<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas>, <http://github.com/jschmidt10#hasAge>, "30"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>>>;p=blaze:history:added;o="2017-01-15T16:11:15.909Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>]
[s=<<<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Tommy>, <http://github.com/jschmidt10#hasLastName>, "Test">>;p=blaze:history:added;o="2017-01-15T16:11:15.909Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>]
[s=<<<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Tommy>, <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>, <http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas>>>;p=blaze:history:added;o="2017-01-15T16:11:15.909Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>]
[s=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas>;p=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#hasAge>;o="30"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>]
[s=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Tommy>;p=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#hasLastName>;o="Test"]
[s=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Tommy>;p=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>;o=<http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas>]
```

Next I try a simple query for a particular subject:

```
SELECT * WHERE { <http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas> ?p ?o }
```

This query yields no results. It seems that none of my queries for a URI are working. I am able to get results when I query for a literal (e.g. `?s ?p "Test"`).

The API I am using to create my query is `BigdataSailRepositoryConnection.prepareQuery().`

Code snippet (Scala) that executes and generates the query:

```
val props = BasicRepositoryProvider.getProperties("./graph.jnl")
val sail = new BigdataSail(props)
val repo = new BigdataSailRepository(sail)

repo.initialize()

val query = "SELECT ?p ?o WHERE { <http://github.com/jschmidt10#person_Thomas> ?p ?o }"
val cxn = repo.getConnection
cxn.begin()
var res = cxn.
    prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query).
    evaluate()

while (res.hasNext) println(res.next)
cxn.close()
repo.shutDown()
```

Comment: Hm, the query should work indeed. I guees it's close to https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Sesame_API_embedded_mode but can you post the whole code snippet that executes and generates the query?

Comment: And what do you get for `SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }` ?

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for the reply. Updated the question with the code snippet. When I run `SELECT DISTINCT ?s`, I get the distinct subjects from my sample set as expected.

Comment: Not a scala expert but your code sample looks legit. Impossible to tell from this what goes wrong, but it's either a bug in Blazegraph or you haven't quite given us a full [mcve]. I'm inclined to think there is some minimal difference (a typo) between your _actual_ code and what you're showing here because the chances that Blazegraph has a bug in such a simple query are quite slim...

Comment: In any case it might be useful to contact Blazegraph support directly.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks for the look - Angela's answer below was my problem. I've updated her answer to reflect my exact code/problem. Next time I'll be sure to include the inserting code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the way you filled the database? You might have characters that are getting encoded strangely, or it looks like you might have excess brackets in your objects.

From the print statement, your URI's are printing extra angled brackets. You are likely using:

```
val subject = valueFactory.createURI("<http://some.url/some/entity>")
```

when you should be doing this (without angled brackets):

```
val subject = valueFactory.createURI("http://some.url/some/entity")
```

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Yes! This was actually my problem. I'll update your answer to reflect what I was doing, but I was inserting my data with angled brackets when they are not needed.